# About the specific shapes of learning curves

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

My model throws up learning curves as I have shown below. Are these fine? I am a beginner and all across the internet I see that as training examples increase the Training score should decrease and then converge. But here the training score is increasing[image] and then converging. Therefore I would like to know does this indicate a bug in my code / something wrong with my input?

Okay I figured out what was wrong with my code.

```
train_sizes , train_accuracy , cv_accuracy = lc(linear_model.LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',penalty='l2',multi_class='ovr'),trainData,multiclass_response_train,train_sizes=np.array([0.1,0.33,0.5,0.66,1.0]),cv=5)
```

I had not entered a regularization parameter for Logistic Regression.

But now,

```
train_sizes , train_accuracy , cv_accuracy = lc(linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1000,solver='lbfgs',penalty='l2',multi_class='ovr'),trainData,multiclass_response_train,train_sizes=np.array([0.1,0.33,0.5,0.66,1.0]),cv=5)
```

The learning curve looks alright.

[image] 
Can anybody tell me why this is so? i.e. with default reg term the training score increases and with lower reg it decreases?

Data details: 10 classes. Images of varying sizes. (Digit Classification - street view digits)

Comment: I suspect that your problem is related to the data you're using. Can you describe your data? How many classes? How many per class? I can imagine that maybe your data got split in such a way that it was tough to learn a good model to distinguish between all classes.

Comment: @NBartley Please check the edited question. Thanks!

Comment: Have you run this code multiple times? Has this been the case each time?

Comment: @NBartley Yes! I have run the code in both cases atleast more than 5 times.

Comment: How many images per class? I'm pretty sure that learning_curve calls StratifiedKFold, so it could be an issue where with few training examples, your classifier does badly on some splits, and that this gets reflected in the averaged score. It's tough to say just by inspection....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of Alex's answer, it looks like the default regularization parameter for your model underfits the data a bit, because when you relaxed regularization, you see 'more appropriate' learning curves. It doesn't matter how many examples you throw at a model that underfits.

As for your concern of why the training score increases in the first case rather than decreases -- it's probably a consequence of the multiclass data you're using. With fewer training examples, you have fewer numbers of images of each class (because `lc` tries to keep the same class distribution in each fold of the cv), so with regularization (if you call C=1 regularization, that is), it may be harder for your model to accurately guess some of the classes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more precise regarding your metrics. What metrics are used here?

**Loss** in general means: lower is better, while **Score** usually means: higher is better.

This also means, that the interpretation of your plot is dependent on the used metrics during training and cross-validation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the related webpage of scipy: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html
The score is typically some measure that needs to be maximized (ROCAUC, accuracy,...). Intuitively you could expect that the more training examples you see the better your model gets and hence the higher the score is. There are however some subtleties regarding overfitting and underfitting that you should keep in mind.